# substrate node-template how to add `total_insuance` with some accounts initial supply

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

I am using susbstrate `node-template`,  I am trying to create my own native token `d-coin` with `xxxxx` amount of total supply, I am using auro consensus, I was able to add some properties to genesis state, below is code, which is working fine, but I am looking set `total supply` and `transaction fees`.

```
pub fn properties() -> Properties {
    let mut properties = Properties::new();
    properties.insert("ss58Format".into(), x.into());
    properties.insert("tokenSymbol".into(), "D".into());
    properties.insert("tokenDecimals".into(), "xx".into());
    properties.insert("totalSupply".into(), "xxxxxxxxx".into());
    properties
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you are using the `pallet_balances` your answer is given [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/how-does-a-substrate-chain-set-the-max-total-supply). Have a look at the [seminar: 6 ways to launch a token](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qkqEfToH8w) it provides information you are probably interested in.

As for transaction fees you should look into `pallet_transaction_payment`, see [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f5c2cecd7efe6dcbc828906794f3c4c41f23c791/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L252-L259) how the default is implemented in the node-template. The seminar provides information about this as well.

Comment: [balance inside GenesisConfig](https://github.com/NodleCode/chain/blob/7e038437f5d31cdc567ff78712d3a9a7d7946437/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L116) of chain_spec.rs what is this for? Shouldn't we considered as `total_insuance`?

Comment: Those are the balances that are set at genesis (e.g. ICO of a chain ). Yes you can view this as the total issuance at genesis. You can also query this if you are using [pallet-balances](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/9795fa31435426137d91936a52cab8e50ebe2f50/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L348-L352).

Answer (score 1):

As my understanding, you can't configure `totalSupply` `Properties` in Substrate.

Substrate has no limit on the total supply of the native token.

It would be helpful if someone could confirm whether I am correct or not.