# CustomSpec Balance doesn't change

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node

following [this](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/add-trusted-nodes/#create-a-custom-chain-specification) tutorial, I created `CustomSpec.json` file and this contains balances like this:

[image]

When I change the default set balance into like this, it doesn't change in polkadotjs frontend.

[image]

Someone please advice me why balance is not changing?
This is code [link](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/default-substrate-node-template)

Comment: it should change, try this again make `customSpecRaw.json` with the desired balance and the chain, then start it again with the new `customSpecRaw.json`

Comment: Firstly, I don't see about block production and block finalization in your terminal.
Secondly, Do you restart your local node again after modifying your chain spec json?

Comment: I generated `CustomSpecRaw.json` using this command `./target/release/node-template build-spec --chain=customSpec.json --raw --disable-default-bootnode > customSpecRaw.json` @ShubhamGupta but still the same balance doesn't change

Comment: Did you purge the chain before restarting it?

Comment: yes @ShubhamGupta

Comment: Please show us reproducible steps. What commands did you run? Every step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the change you wanted. I did the following:

1. Cloned the repo:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/default-substrate-node-template.git
```

2. Compiled

```bash
cargo build –release
```

3. Followed the tutorial for change the specs:

```bash
./target/release/node-template build-spec --disable-default-bootnode --chain local > customSpec.json
```

Convert it to raw without change

```bash
./target/release/node-template build-spec --chain=customSpec.json --raw --disable-default-bootnode > customSpecRaw.json
```

4. Run it:

```bash
./target/release/node-template \ 
  --base-path /tmp/node01 \ 
  --chain ./customSpecRaw.json \ 
  --port 30333 \ 
  --ws-port 9945 \ 
  --rpc-port 9933 \ 
  --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \ 
  --validator \ 
  --rpc-methods Unsafe \ 
  --name MyNode01
```

Take capture:

[image]

Stop it

5. modify the specs

[image]

Convert it to raw after change

```bash
./target/release/node-template build-spec --chain=customSpec.json --raw --disable-default-bootnode > customSpecRaw.json
```

6. Removed /tmp/node01 folder

```bash
rm -rf /tmp/node01
```

7. run it again:

```bash
./target/release/node-template \  --base-path /tmp/node01 \ 
  --chain ./customSpecRaw.json \ 
  --port 30333 \ 
  --ws-port 9945 \ 
  --rpc-port 9933 \ 
  --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \ 
  --validator \ 
  --rpc-methods Unsafe \ 
  --name MyNode01
```

Take capture:

[image]

Comment: thank you @Xavier, is this the way to set `total_supply` for the chain?

Comment: @Ganesh11 no, I think your answer is in this other question https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/how-does-a-substrate-chain-set-the-max-total-supply

Comment: I am confused @Xavier, Whats that `total balance` is then?

Comment: @Ganesh11 since you are not giving context, i guess you are refering to the total amount an account have of an specific token.

Comment: yes exactly @Xavier